# String splitting with unknown punctuation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, join, split

I am building an application that downloads sentences and parses them for a word game. I don't know in advance what punctuation the text will contain.

I'd like to be able to split up the sentence/s, examine them for part of speech tag, and if the correct tag is found, replace it with `"       "`, and rejoin them back in order.

```
text = "some string, with punctuation- for example: things I don't know about, that may or may not have     whitespaces and random characters % !!"
```

How can I split it into an array so that I can pass the parser over each word, and rejoin them *in order*, bearing in mind that `string.split(//)` seems to need to know what punctuation I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you have to rejoin them? Why not just use the original string? Or are you doing some sort of transformation?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "part of speech tag"?

Comment: When you reassemble the sentence after making whatever change you need to make, do you need to preserve everything else about the sentence, including the specific whitespace?

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Peter. I want to send each word to a part of speech tagger, and depending on the type of word I'm looking, replace it with "______ ", then join the whole sentence back together, the only difference being that I have replaced one word with " ______"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` is useful when you can more easily describe the delimiters than the parts to be extracted. In your case, you can more easily describe the parts to be extracted rather than the delimiters, in which case `scan` is more suited. It is a wrong decision to use `split`. You should you `scan`.

```
text.scan(/[\w']+/)
# => ["some", "string", "with", "punctuation", "for", "example", "things", "I", "don't", "know", "about", "that", "may", "or", "may", "not", "have", "whitespaces", "and", "random", "characters"]
```

If you want to replace the matches, there is even more reason to not use `split`. In that case, you should use `gsub`.

```
text.gsub(/[\w']+/) do |word|
 if word.is_of_certain_part_of_speech?
   "___"  # Replace it with `"___"`.
 else
   word   # Put back the original word.
 end
end
```

Comment: This is a useful step. How would I best go about retaining the punctuation and whitespace in the original string for joining them back together? Creating a dictionary that maps the original word with trailing punctuation and whitespace onto the new list of words (thereby only replacing the word that is transformed?)